# Which Version of MVVM Light should I be using with Windows Phone 7.8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm, mvvm-light

I want to start developing in windows phone 7.8 but not sure which version of  [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/) to use. I got to use VS 2010 since as far as I know you can't program wp7 in Vs2012. The newest version of MVVM light seems to only support 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Visual Studio 2012 you can also develop Windows Phone 7 apps. Just select the appropiate target OS when creating a new project.

MVVM Light v3 should always work as it was build for Visual Studio 2010.

**This is how it looks on my machine:**

New project screen in Visual Studio 2012:
[image: New project screen in Visual Studio 2012]

Windows Phone OS version selection box showing 7.1 & 8.0:
[image: Windows Phone OS version selection box showing 7.1 & 8.0]

Comment: What do you mean "select the appropriate target?". I only see windows phone 8. No windows 7 phone.

Comment: Create WP Project for WP7, then install MVVM Light from Nuget Package Manager.